# Dropzone: cannot trigger queue complete

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm using Backbone, so on render I set a timeout and trigger the script,this is working fine, however I cannot trigger a queue complete state so I can then react in my view.

```
onRender: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {

        var myDropzone = $(".dropzone").dropzone({
          paramName: 'file',
          clickable: true,
          maxFilesize: 1,
          uploadMultiple: true,
          parallelUploads: 1,
          autoProcessQueue: false,
          thumbnailWidth: 200,
          thumbnailHeight: 200,
          maxThumbnailFilesize: 3,

          init: function() {
            var totalFiles = 0,
              completeFiles = 0;
            this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
              console.log('added');
              totalFiles += 1;
            });
            this.on("removed file", function(file) {
              console.log('removed');
              totalFiles -= 1;
            });
            this.on("complete", function(file) {
              console.log('complete');
              completeFiles += 1;
              if (completeFiles === totalFiles) {
                console.log('done');
              }
            });

          },

          queuecomplete: function() {
            console.log('queuecomplete');
          },

          accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log('accept');

            var imageType = file.type;
            var imageHeight = file.height;
            var imageWidth = file.width;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = handleReaderLoad;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            function handleReaderLoad(evt) {
              console.log('handleReaderLoad');

              $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                timeout: 5000,
                url: "image",
                data: {
                  'client': $('#client-upload option:selected').val(),
                  'height': imageHeight,
                  'width': imageWidth,
                  'type': file.type,
                  'base64': evt.target.result
                },
              });
            }

            done();
          },
        });

        myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
          console.log('complete');
        });

      }, 1000);
    },
```

Uploading two images has this in console:

```
added upload.js:40
accept upload.js:62
added upload.js:40
accept upload.js:62
x2 handleReaderLoad
```